# Projecting indexeddb data in browser after inserting using jsstore

Tags: indexeddb

[image]Projecting indexeddb data in browser after inserting using jsstore shows all data in each column.Is there duplication of data ? why its projecting like this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or more info. Its not clear, what you are asking?

Comment: i added screenshot.Here we can see all data which are stored in table while clicking on column also.

Comment: Indexedb is nosql database, it stores data in the form of object.

Comment: Are you getting any problems due to this ?

Comment: Object stores store data redundantly. This is called denormalization. Better speed but more storage space. But storage space is cheap and speed is not.

Comment: so,this is for analyzing purpose only,my all object data stored once in table not in column also right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column in indexeddb is a key of object and table is object store. In your case lets say the key is - ArticleId and the column ArticleId is indexed by JsStore.

Now lets see about index in idb -

> An index is a specialized object store for looking up records in
>   another object store, called the referenced object store. The index is
>   a persistent key-value storage where the value part of its records is
>   the key part of a record in the referenced object store. The records
>   in an index are automatically populated whenever records in the
>   referenced object store are inserted, updated, or deleted. Each record
>   in an index can point to only one record in its referenced object
>   store, but several indexes can reference the same object store. When
>   the object store changes, all indexes that refer to the object store
>   are automatically updated.

So basically when you add index on a key, an special object store is maintained by indexeddb in order to search the records.

When you define column in JsStore - JsStore automatically add the index on that column, so that we can search on that column.

So the data is not repeated in columns and tables. The column is just referencing to the respective primary key , and using primary key it can access the actual stored value. The browser is only showing relationship between data.

Hope this will give you more info about indexeddb columns, index and how they are stored.

For more Info, please take a look at MDN Article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Comment: Thanks.now, I am getting